# Home-made Python package not found in lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless, python-packaging

I am trying to deploy a function to AWS using serverless + serverless-python-requirements plugin.

The function is using a package on requirements.txt which points to a github repository (it is downloaded and my IDE finds it on my venv).

When I push the artifact to deploy it, I trigger a function that uses it and I get a

```py
Unable to import module '<implementing_function>': No module named '<home-made package>'
```

If I download the artifact from S3, I see that the directory + contents are there, and I've already checked and re-checked the `setup.py` and the `__init__.py` files to make sure I'm not missing anything.

This is to move away from the good old git submodule approach.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** These are the contents of the artifact:

```
total 192
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 user  staff    320 Nov 21 10:21 Cerberus-1.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 user  staff    352 Nov 21 10:21 Jinja2-2.10.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  staff    256 Nov 21 10:21 MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  staff    256 Nov 21 10:21 PyYAML-5.1.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@  7 user  staff    224 Nov 21 10:21 args-0.1.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff   9316 Jan  1  2098 args.py
drwxr-xr-x@ 17 user  staff    544 Nov 21 10:21 bin
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 user  staff    480 Nov 21 10:21 boto3
drwxr-xr-x@  9 user  staff    288 Nov 21 10:21 boto3-1.9.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 42 user  staff   1344 Nov 21 10:21 botocore
drwxr-xr-x@  9 user  staff    288 Nov 21 10:21 botocore-1.12.253.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@  7 user  staff    224 Nov 21 10:21 cached_property-1.5.1.dist-info
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff   4277 Jan  1  2098 cached_property.py
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 user  staff    320 Nov 21 10:21 cerberus
drwxr-xr-x@  7 user  staff    224 Nov 21 10:21 certifi
drwxr-xr-x@  9 user  staff    288 Nov 21 10:21 certifi-2019.9.11.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 43 user  staff   1376 Nov 21 10:21 chardet
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 user  staff    320 Nov 21 10:21 chardet-3.0.4.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 user  staff    352 Nov 21 10:21 clint
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 user  staff    352 Nov 21 10:21 clint-0.5.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 20 user  staff    640 Nov 21 10:21 corporate_ops_utils
drwxr-xr-x@  6 user  staff    192 Nov 21 10:21 corporatebot
drwxr-xr-x@ 14 user  staff    448 Nov 21 10:21 dateutil
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  staff    256 Nov 21 10:21 docopt-0.6.2.dist-info
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff  19946 Jan  1  2098 docopt.py
drwxr-xr-x@ 17 user  staff    544 Nov 21 10:21 docutils
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  staff    256 Nov 21 10:21 docutils-0.15.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  staff    256 Nov 21 10:21 ec2_metadata-2.0.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff   8561 Jan  1  2098 ec2_metadata.py
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 user  staff    352 Nov 21 10:21 idna
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  staff    256 Nov 21 10:21 idna-2.8.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 30 user  staff    960 Nov 21 10:21 jinja2
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 user  staff    352 Nov 21 10:21 jmespath
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 user  staff    320 Nov 21 10:21 jmespath-0.9.4.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@  9 user  staff    288 Nov 21 10:21 markupsafe
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff    338 Jan  1  1980 ops-slack-bot.iml
drwxr-xr-x@  9 user  staff    288 Nov 21 10:21 python_dateutil-2.8.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 21 user  staff    672 Nov 21 10:21 requests
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  staff    256 Nov 21 10:21 requests-2.22.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff    134 Jan  1  2098 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 user  staff    512 Nov 21 10:21 s3transfer
drwxr-xr-x@  9 user  staff    288 Nov 21 10:21 s3transfer-0.1.13.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  staff    256 Nov 21 10:21 six-1.13.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff  33045 Jan  1  2098 six.py
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 user  staff    512 Nov 21 10:21 urllib3
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  staff    256 Nov 21 10:21 urllib3-1.25.7.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 20 user  staff    640 Nov 21 10:21 yaml
```

My custom package is in the `corporate_ops_utils` directory and the package name is `corporate-ops-utils`.

The entrypoint/handler for my function is `corporatebot/backend_operation_message.receive` and the file that is throwing the import error is `corporatebot.backend_operation_message`. Since `event_receive` and `frontend_operation_message_receive` don't use this custom package, they work without problems.

In `serverless.yml`, the three functions are defined:

```
functions:
  event_receive:
    handler: corporatebot/event.receive
    timeout: 3 # optional, in seconds, default is 6
    memorySize: 128
    events:
      - http:
          path: event/receive
          method: post
          cors: true
  frontend_operation_message_receive:
    handler: corporatebot/frontend_operation_message.receive
    timeout: 30 # optional, in seconds, default is 6
    memorySize: 128
  backend_operation_message_receive:
    handler: corporatebot/backend_operation_message.receive
    timeout: 30 # optional, in seconds, default is 6
    memorySize: 128
```

Comment: Where in your directory structure does this file live relative to where the module lives?

Comment: Hi @MichaelSilverstein thanks for the reply. I just added more info for clarification.